# Is it possible to change AppName in iTunesConnect before release (use a dummy name while in testflight phase)

Tags: app-store-connect, rename, testflight, bundle-identifier

I know this has been asked before, but testflight has recently been changed and adopted by apple, and now the app is required to be created through iTunesConnect.

Now, is it possible to create an app with a dummy name for now, and change it later?

An alternative solution could be deleting the old-named app, and creating a brand new one. Then, I suppose I will also need to remove the previous bundleID from my dev account and create a new one for the new build with the new name. Assuming I don't purchase specific licenses for the dummy bundleID, do I suffer any kind of loss with this method? (like bundleID quota for dev account or similar things like "x number of things I can have" is now reduced by 1 kind of things).

A bonus question: There are app names with the format X - Y, for example: "FooApp - Return of the foo". Is this specified under appName only? Does it make sense to create a bundleID www.user.FooApp and have your name "FooApp - Return of the foo"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer : yes.

I changed my app name in XCODE, and registered a matching profile, including certs in Itunes Connect. It worked as expected.

Bonus Q: as I understand it the "www-xx-com" is simply an identifier. It doesn't have any intelligence built into it.

Please Note: I was doing internal testing. Not External...

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to point out now that I have gone further into the project, YES it is indeed changeable.

When you upload your archive to iTunesConnect, you are then allowed change the app name where you set the other metadata. You can try any different name (not related to bundleID), and see if it is reserved or not.